# Number of splits and map tasks in hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

I am new to Map Reduce programming, I have written my algorithm in python and i need to run 'n' map instances of the same program(my algorithm) on 'n' dataset. Since my code is in python, i am using hadoopstreaming for my code.

Hadoopstreaming documentation suggests here - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#How+do+I+process+files%2C+one+per+map%3F, "Generate a file containing the full HDFS path of the input files. Each map task would get one file name as input."

So, i created a text file with path for each of my dataset file. Just to test, i have written word count program from this - http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/ . And in my map function, i have written the below piece of code before doing the actual word count

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # obtain filename from file list
    filename = line.rstrip('\n')
    localfilename = ntpath.basename(filename)
    os.environ("hadoop dfs -get"+line+ " " + localfilename)
```

*Q1. So my understanding is that each line will be given as a split to my map function and so the number of split should be the number of split or line in my main file. I have three filenames in my main file, but i can see there are 2 splits created. Why is it so?*

*Q2. And my job is failing, i dont know why, where to check these log files?*

*Q3. And apart from that, i have another option handle my requirement, placing all my three dataset in to one file and separate it with some specific delimiter, then can set this conf.set(“textinputformat.record.delimiter”, “specific-delimiter”) , but the problem is it has to be done in java. Also, in many forums, it is written to write custom record reader to achieve this. since i am not good in java, i am writing my implementation in python, is there anyway to set this parameter or do it without writing java code?*

*Q4. Is there any other option in hadoop which i am missing to handle my requirement?*

```
hduser@master:~/code$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar -mapper "python $PWD/fileprocess.py" -reducer "python $PWD/reduce.py" -input final.txt -output output.txt
14/09/16 05:27:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
packageJobJar: [/home/hduser/tmp/hadoop-unjar4045267665479713934/] [] /tmp/streamjob4078572719514334736.jar tmpDir=null
14/09/16 05:27:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.0.0.4:8032
14/09/16 05:27:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.0.0.4:8032
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
14/09/16 05:27:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
14/09/16 05:27:34 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1410171456875_0012
14/09/16 05:27:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1410171456875_0012 to ResourceManager at master/10.0.0.4:8032
14/09/16 05:27:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1410171456875_0012/
14/09/16 05:27:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1410171456875_0012
14/09/16 05:27:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1410171456875_0012 running in uber mode : false
14/09/16 05:27:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/09/16 05:28:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1410171456875_0012_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** Hadoop will split up each file as it sees fit and can make no guarantees as to which lines go where. You will need to put your lines into separate files in order to ensure they are handled by separate mappers.

For your example, if you have three filenames, instead of putting them all into a single `/TEMP/files` file you should create three files in a subfolder, each with one filename and then add them to your job like so: `-input /TEMP/files/*`. That will give you the behavior you're looking for.

Note that you won't get any locality for your data. The mapper which will get the first file reference might need to fetch it from another node. Depending on the size of your cluster, you might be more likely than not to have to go to the network for most of the files that you are processing.

**Q2:** The command line output only tells you about the java container failure and not about the actual error from python. To get that you should go to the job tracker page: `http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp`

From there you can find your job under *failed jobs*. Click on a failed task on that page and pick one of the options in the *Task logs* column. From there you will see the stderr output of your python script.

You are doing something strange with os.environ. You should be using subprocess to execute commands. For example:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["/usr/bin/hadoop", "dfs", "-get", line, localfilename])
```

**Q3:** I'm not exactly sure what the requirement is here. Are you talking about the actual files which are being referenced by the files above and you will then be getting directly via -get into your mappers? You are processing them manually so it doesn't matter what format they are in since they are not being passed into map/reduce.

**Q4:** It looks like you have some files that you want to process in parallel but you don't need to use map/reduce. You basically just want to take advantage of the fact that you have a hadoop cluster available with a bunch of cpu. That's fine and can work but you're not really using hadoop for anything other than shuffling work to slaves.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes that was wrong, i just corrected it. And apart from that from your first answer, you mentioned that by giving -input /TEMP/files/* will give the behaviour i am looking for. So, in that case, does that satisfy my requirement of each map task handling one file. Because my data should not mix since i am doing some functional dependancy stuff, mixing dataset will completely affect my requirement.

Comment: Yes, I believe that two different files will not be sent to the same mapper.
I'm wondering though, why does it matter? You can handle each file from our input independently even though they are processed by the same mapper.

Comment: Because, i am going to write my algorithm on map function which will compare each tuple with other within that dataset, so if other dataset mix with it, then there will be a complete mess..

Comment: And in my question 3, i said, copying all my data in to a single file and add some delimeters after each dataset data and then use this approach, so that data till one delimiter will be read by single map task, but it is mentioned in java, i am looking for something similar in python- http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/

Comment: This solution also seems to be a good one.I created three files and placed all three in this -input /TEMP/files/* and then executed map alone to just print the data, three splits and three map tasks were created as you mentioned and printed all the data from all maps. Is there a way to see which data coming from which mapper? like map id or counter id kind of? If not, how to iterate a custom number as a key for each map task like map task one outputs records with key 1, map task two outputs records with key 2, etc.. This is to make sure that the data from file2 is not mixed in map1 task.